# Moving elements to other page regions

Tags: theming, breadcrumbs

I want to move the page breadcrumb to the content region in Bartik (D7.)

I assume it is theming but I can't find anywhere (style.css, layout.css) where the breadcrumb is assigned in the first place.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I will again answer my own question here:

The change is made in the *page.tpl.php* template found the the template directory of your theme.

In this case, all I had to do is move the following:

```
<?php if ($breadcrumb): ?>
  <div id="breadcrumb"><?php print $breadcrumb; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

from it's present location under the *main-wrapper* to its new location under the *content* heading. Then I cleared the theme registry cache.

Make sure that if you move an "if" statement, that you always move its corresponding "endif" statement too.

:)